# Will it always be possible to play an audio file with the HTML5 <video> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I've always noticed that you can play audio files with the HTML5 <video> tag. It seems really handy, considering that you only have to use 1 element to play videos and audio. An example would be [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oacLrnvv/).

```
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" controls></video>
```

My first question is: **Is this something that is here to stay, or is this a fluke that browsers plan on removing later on?**

And if not, **how do I know if a file is a video or audio using JavaScript?** Because if I'm correct, can't *.ogg* files be video **or** audio? I'm trying to make a mediaplayer app for Chromebooks but I need to be able to differentiate audios from videos.

Comment: There are differences between the two elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: Of course. However, there aren't many differences between their properties. Video has more, such as width, height, and poster, obviously because a video has all those things and audio doesnt. It just seems like "video" is more flexible. If it's a video, cool; if it's an audio, okay, no poster and stuff. A video can play an audio, but an audio can play a video. It just seems nifty and it would be a shame if browsers did away with this. In fact, wouldn't it be more practical to make ONE element? Perhaps "media"?

Comment: @RickyAYoder If you are big into separating look-and-feel and information, then they are different. For me, it's the same argument as "If i make divs look like a table with CSS, why not just make it a table"; well, because one is a table, and another isn't. Same here. Imagine somebody developing a search engine for visually impaired, it may make sense to place <video>-heavy sites lower in the results than <audio>-heavy ones. And this is just one example, i can come up at the top of my head, where they are truly different.